# some websites not accessing still

Tags: 13.04, internet, websites

I have seen this problem before, some of them were solved by changing DNS of their network connection. But my problem not solved by doing this.

I have tried Google DNS, but I still have the same problem. I am unable able to access yahoo.com from my browser. What else can I do , I don't get it.

Please can someone suggest a way that I can get complete access. Thank you.

The only thing I am getting in my browser(Firefox) is **waiting for yahoo.com**

Details:

Ubuntu 13.04

BSNL Broadband -DSL Connection

Information:

```
raja@raja-OEM:~$ host yahoo.com
yahoo.com has address 98.139.183.24
yahoo.com has address 206.190.36.45
yahoo.com has address 98.138.253.109
yahoo.com mail is handled by 1 mta7.am0.yahoodns.net.
yahoo.com mail is handled by 1 mta6.am0.yahoodns.net.
yahoo.com mail is handled by 1 mta5.am0.yahoodns.net.
raja@raja-OEM:~$ host yahoo.com 8.8.8.8
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases: 

yahoo.com has address 98.139.183.24
yahoo.com has address 206.190.36.45
yahoo.com has address 98.138.253.109
yahoo.com mail is handled by 1 mta7.am0.yahoodns.net.
yahoo.com mail is handled by 1 mta6.am0.yahoodns.net.
yahoo.com mail is handled by 1 mta5.am0.yahoodns.net.
raja@raja-OEM:~$ ping yahoo.com
PING yahoo.com (98.138.253.109) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_req=1 ttl=47 time=404 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_req=2 ttl=50 time=388 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_req=3 ttl=47 time=453 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_req=4 ttl=48 time=433 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_req=5 ttl=47 time=419 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_req=6 ttl=50 time=400 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_req=7 ttl=47 time=433 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_req=8 ttl=50 time=420 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_req=9 ttl=47 time=434 ms
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.ne1.yahoo.com (98.138.253.109): icmp_req=10 ttl=51 time=413 ms


[1]+  Stopped                 ping yahoo.com
raja@raja-OEM:~$ curl -I yahoo.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Redirect
Date: Sun, 23 Jun 2013 13:37:59 GMT
Connection: close
Server: YTS/1.20.13
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Language: en
Location: http://www.yahoo.com/
Content-Length: 211

raja@raja-OEM:~$
```

**Progress:**

I have tried to gain access with https://www.unifiedremote.com/ but it said that it was an `Untrusted Connection`

Comment: Please be more specific about your "problem" and "not able to access". What is the exact error you get: "Connection refused", "Connection timed out", "Unable to resolve",... etc. If you have read  more of the DNS issues, then you've also seen how to debug it. Start to provide more information in your question. Include the output of commands like `host yahoo.com`, `host yahoo.com 8.8.8.8`, `ping yahoo.com`, `curl -I yahoo.com` and what happens if you open it with HTTPS directly. Also: do you have a proxy server configured? Do other devices on the network suffer from the same issue?

Comment: @gertvdijk http://paste.ubuntu.com/5792538/

Comment: @maggotbrain I provided the information what have asked by one of our member. I am completely not agreed with your decision.Thank you.

Comment: @Jai Excellent. If someone else is helping you out, cool. Glad to hear it.

Comment: Looks all okay **you do not have any DNS issues**. `https://www.unifiedremote.com/` is indeed showing an invalid certificate - that's their fault. I think your issue is with Firefox. Have you tried another browser? And have you checked the connection settings? (disable proxy in Firefox).

Comment: @gertvdijk I have also tried in midori and Chromium.The results are same.

Comment: Is your system's clock at a relatively accurate time?

Comment: Or this may just be an annoying MTU-related issue. What is the MTU on your interface? And also see this: [How to diagnose a reliably unreliable connection?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11107/23363)

Comment: @gertvdijk I have removed resolv.conf by studying one answer at our site and now after restart I lost complete access , even google also I cant access. help me!

Comment: **Do not remove `/etc/resolv.conf`.** It is needed for proper functioning of name resolving. I think recreating an empty file (`sudo touch /etc/resolv.conf`) and restarting Network Manager (`sudo restart network-manager`) will get you back to the situation before removing it. Network Manager will overwrite all contents of the file anyway.

Comment: @gertvdijk brother the command you mentioned above are not helped much but i re enabled services as past by downloading resolvconf deb file from ubuntu packages and installed it. services as previously are started but issues still remained.

Comment: The problem still there.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem .The problems seem to vanish when i used pppoeconf to connect. install pppoeconf and connect using it.

Comment: This only applies to the question if OP also uses PPPoE to establish an internet connection. And that information is not in the question at the moment.

Comment: DSL connection is possible here with PPPoE only and that package was pre installed. @gertvdijk +1 .